# Combine all elements to a flux to mono

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

This is a simplified example of the problem I am facing.

```
Flux<String> fluxString = Flux.just("A","B","C");
Mono<String> monoString = Mono.just("Original");
```

Expected result is this

```
Mono<String> expectedresult = "Original A B C";
```

Approach 1 -> I can either wait for all elements of the flux to be recieved and then combine them with the mono

or

Approach 2-> combine each elements of the flux to mono and update the original mono with new value before the next flux element is received.
Which of the above approach will work for me?

I tried approach 2 with following code

```
Flux<String> fluxfrommono = monoString.flatMapMany(a-> Mono.just(a).repeat());
Flux.zip(fluxfrommono ,fluxString  ,(a,b)-> a+b)
```

But this produces "Original A","Original B","Original C"-> the Original String does not get updated with new value for each flux element.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `concatWith` the `monoString` with `fluxString`, and `reduce` it to a `Mono<String>`.

Comment: this is indeed a more fireproof approach, as `concat` will ensure that `Original` is always emitted before `A,B,C`

Answer (score 0):

Code that worded for me-

```
Flux<String> fluxString = Flux.just("A","B","C");
Mono<String> monoString = Mono.just("Original");
Mono<String> combinedString = fluxString.reduce((a,b)->a+b);
Mono<String> expectedresult = Mono.zip(monoString ,combinedString ,(a,b)->a+b);
```

Comment: this approach works, with the caveat that if `monoString` takes longer than the entire `fluxString` to emit "Original", you'll get `"A B C Original"` instead. (but here it is not possible as `just` is evaluated synchronously, so `zip` will effectively always let `monoString` complete before `combinedString`)